# I am facing issue with eclipse reflection - not working

Tags: eclipse, reflection

I am facing issue with eclipse reflection - not working

please find the snapshot.
Please guide me which setting I need to change for this to work
I am using eclipse kepler
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found out the solution, after getting to know that this is called auto-complete.

```
Preferences -> java -> editor -> Content Assist -> Advanced > Restore Default  
Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Content Assist -> Restore Defaults
```

Thanks for bearing with me